# Simple Collision Detection Project

Tags: java, processing, collision-detection

I am a newbie with coding and doing a collision detection project for my assignment. I think I got the Algorithm right but my problem is how will I access the object from my ArrayList I created and remove the object once collision is detected. Please see my code and help me to improve it to add the remove() from it. I added a boolean variable to check if true or false then do the remove function.

**My end goal is to remove the ghost when it collides with the green ball**

```java
    ArrayList<Greenball> array1 = new ArrayList<Greenball>();
    ArrayList<Ghost> array2 = new ArrayList<Ghost>();

    void setup(){
      size(1000,500);
      
      
    }
    
    void draw(){
      background(255);
      
      
      for(int i = 0; i < array1.size() ; i++){
       array1.get(i).move();
       array1.get(i).display();
      }
      
      for (int i = 0; i < array2.size() ; i++){
       array2.get(i).move();
       array2.get(i).display();
      }
    }
    
    void mousePressed(){
      if (array1.size() != 5) array1.add(new Greenball(int(mouseX),int(mouseY), 40, 40)); //max at 5
    }
    
    void keyPressed(){
      if (array2.size() != 5)array2.add(new Ghost(int(random(40,960)), int(random(40,460)), 40, 40)); //max at 5
```

---

```
class Ghost{
  
  PImage ghost;
  int x,y,w,h,xSpeed,ySpeed;
  int pixelSize = 40;
  Ghost(int x_, int y_, int w_, int h_){
  x = x_;
  y = y_;
  w = w_;
  h = h_;  
  xSpeed = int(random(-10,10));
  ySpeed = int(random(1,10));  
  }
  
  void move(){
   x = x + xSpeed;
   y = y + ySpeed;
   
   if(x > width-pixelSize || x < 0){
    xSpeed = xSpeed * -1; 
   }
   if(y > height-pixelSize || y < 0){
    ySpeed = ySpeed * -1; 
   }
    
  }
  
  void display(){
   ghost = loadImage("greenghost.png");
   image(ghost,x,y,w,h);
}
```

---

```
class Greenball{
  
 PImage g;
 int x,y,w,h,xSpeed,ySpeed;
 int pixelSize = 40;
 boolean alive=true;
 Greenball(int x_, int y_, int w_, int h_){
   x = x_;
   y = y_;
   w = w_;
   h = h_;
   xSpeed = int(random(-10,10));
   ySpeed = int(random(1,10));
 }
 
 void move(){
   x = x + xSpeed;
   y = y + ySpeed;
   
   if(x > width-pixelSize || x < 0){
    xSpeed = xSpeed * -1; 
   }
   if(y > height-pixelSize || y < 0){
    ySpeed = ySpeed * -1; 
   }
 }
 
 void display(){
   g = loadImage("green.png");
   image(g,x,y,w,h);
 }
 
 
 void checkForCollision(Ghost ghost){
   float d = dist(x,y,ghost.x,ghost.y);
   float r1 = (x+y)/2;
   float r2 = (ghost.x + ghost.y)/2;
   
   if (d < r1 + r2) alive = false;
   else alive = true;
   }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got stuck on how will I remove the ghost object once it collides with the green ball. I am not sure how will I do it.

Comment: "how will I access the object from my ArrayList" Access for what? You had to access it often for the other parts of your program. What is different? Why do you want to "remove the object once collision is detected". Is simply marking it as "exorcised" not an option? You could just skip the exorcised ghosts from displaying and from the other logic of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Add the *Collision Detection Function* inside `draw()` and run two nested `for` loops so that you check if any of the `Ghosts` is colliding with any of the `Greenballs`
You can replace your draw function with the following code:

```
void draw() {
  background(255);

   // loop through all the Ghosts
   for(int i = 0; i < array2.size(); i++) {

     //move and display the Ghosts
     array2.get(i).move();
     array2.get(i).display();

     /*
      * For every Ghost, check if that Ghost is colliding with any Greenball.
      * Here you are checking collision with each Ghost for each Greenball.
      */
     for (int j = 0; j < array2.size(); j++) { // for each Greenball,
       if (array1.get(i).checkForCollision(array2.get(j)) { // if any Ghost is Colliding with it,
         array1.get(j).alive = false; // then set "alive = false" for it     
       }     
     }
   }

  // loop through all the Greenballs in reverse order, so that each and every Greenball is checked
  for(int i = array1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array1.get(i).alive = false) { // if any Greenball is dead,
      array1.remove(i); // then remove it
    } else { // else, move and display it.
      array1.get(i).move();
      array1.get(i).display();
    }
  }
 
}
```

Suggestion: You don't need to `loadImage()` everytime you display the `Ghost` or `Greenball` as it is very taxing on your system. Just use `ghost = loadImage("ghost.png")` once in the Constructor and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where do you call the `checkForCollision` method from. I think the best place for it is the `draw` method. Try replace your second loop with the following code:

```
Iterator<Ghost> ghostIterator = array2.iterator();  // get iterator object
while (ghostIterator.hasNext()) {
    Ghost ghost = ghostIterator.next();             // get current ghost object
    ghost.move();                                   // recalculate position
    boolean collided = false;
    for (int i = 0, len = array1.size(); i < len; i++) {
        if (array1.get(i).checkForCollision(ghost)) {   // check for collision
            ghostIterator.remove(ghost);               // remove current ghost if it collided
            collided = true;
            break;               // stop inside loop due to collision detected
        }
        if (!collided) {
            ghost.display();  // if ghost isn`t collided display it
        }
    }
}
```

Please note you should change return type of the `checkForCollision` method from `void` to `boolean` and returns calculated `alive` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
void draw(){
  background(0);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < gball1.size() ; i++){
    Greenball gball = gball1.get(i);
    gball.move();
    gball.display(); 
   }
  

  for(int i = 0; i < ghost2.size() ; i++){
    
    Ghost ghost = ghost2.get(i);
    ghost.move();
    ghost.display();
    
    for(int e = 0; e < gball1.size(); e++){
      Greenball b = gball1.get(e);
      if(ghost.ifCollided(b)){
        ghost2.remove(i);
      }
    }
   }

}
```